# Test ionic app with real http requests - Integration Test

Tags: angular, testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, protractor

I want to test my app and I am not sure which kind of test to use for which purpose.

I have an app that loads a page with the given data, then starts a http request (with a provider) to load and update the data in the view. If you click on some piece of data, the next page gets the data already there and then loads the rest and updates and so on. I want to test the update functions and the http requests.

I want to test my app from end to end, so I tried using e2e testing (with pretractor). But I found no way to check the data in the background, e.g. the data comming back from the server or the data held in my data model. Besides, my information is that the e2e test should be used for UI testing rather than function testing.

So I tried unit-testing (with Jasmine and Karma). I can access the right functions and variables, but I found no way to use the real http requests (not mockups) for my tests. Furthermore I need the result from the last page to send the right http request for the current page and I understand that this is not what unit testing is supposed to do.

I think I need some kind of integration test, but I have no idea how to implement this with ionic 3. 
So: Which test should I use and how to use it to to what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karma is only for testing browser-based code and not for testing your `http` requests.
Setup a `MockBackend` for it.

But if you have to rely on the real data, then allow certain or all requests to pass through like

```
angular.module('yourModule').run(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
}
```

in your tests.

**Update:**

For *Angular 2* and above, you won't find `passThrough` method on the `MockBackend` class.
But you can include the real `XHRBackend` as a dependency to your "fake backend provider", then use the "real backend" to perform an `http` request to the server for any URLs that aren't handled by a mock response.

Refer this blog for more: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/11/24/angular-2-mockbackend-example-for-backendless-development

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you think I should use unit testing?
Unfortunately I think your second suggestion only works with angular 1, I have to use angular 4. 
Is there a way to do the same thing in angular 4?

Comment: I mean you don't use real backend for testing because with `Karma`/`e2e` in app, you are trying to test the app (and not the backend) and that should ideally not require use of any real data.
If you need to test your backend, then ideally you will have your `mocha` tests configured for that with the backend.